# Sculpture brush animation shape key alternative?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, multiresolution, sculpt-mode, brushes

I'm a beginner at Blender, and would be incredibly thankful for some advice: I have created an alpha texture sculpt brush from an image. It works fine and looks great on the plane where I used it, but I want the brush imprint to appear slowly as an animation. I managed to do this with shape keys, but then I had to first subdivide the plane really a lot for it to look good, since if I understood it correctly I could not use the multires modifier with shape keys? All this works, but my computer runs so slowly I am not able to continue making something out of this (work on animating cameras, add liquid etc). Is there another better way to animate (from a flat surface to a surface with a detailed imprint done with a sculpture brush)?

Edit: The image I have used for the brush (jpg) is a photo of a closed eye with all the wrinkles, skin pores and hairs around it. It turned out really nice, but I want it to appear slowly from an initially flat plane. Maybe this is something I shouldn't do with a brush at all, but with an image texture? I don't want it to cover the whole plain, just appear on one spot of the plane.

Comment: Screenshots would help, but I might suggest tracing the bitmap into vector graphics with Inkscape or an online converter, importing that as curves, then using it to cut the mesh, then extruding the shape of the image from the plane by zero distance, and then moving it in the shape key so the shape key makes it extrude. Can you add screenshots of the various parts so I can walk it through with a test set up and make sure it works / give an accurate tutorial?

Comment: @TheLabCat thank you! :) I added some clarification, hope that makes it more clear? It's not a bitmap, and not a very graphic image. It's really a photo (jpg) and as I only press the sculpt draw brush with the texture one single time, it made a rather photorealistic imprint of the used photo on the surface, appearing and disappearing with the shape key.

Comment: Sounds like the job for a displacement texture over an animated displacement modifier